# What does the 'I' in IObservable<T> or IObserver<T> mean?

Tags: system.reactive, rxjs

I'm trying to learn/understand Rx, specifically RxJS, and keep seeing references to IObservable, IObserver, etc.

Can anyone tell me what the leading `I` means and/or where it comes from?

From my searching, it looks like the `<T>` is for the type.  If this is wrong or naive, I'd appreciate some clarification on this as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Interface. The naming convention comes from .net, where purely abstract classes have a special construct in the framework called Interface. Javascript, a duck typing language, does not have anything like this. However you still have an abstract concept of a contract you are expected to fulfill.

Comment: .net didn't invent interfaces and that naming convention is pretty common. Agree with the rest though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ye olden days of MFC for C++, Microsoft had Hungarian notation down to a very irritating artform, where all concrete classes were prefixed with `C` and their COM interfaces with `I`, this does help avoid the conflict where a COM interface and class might share the same name and so muddy your project.

Part of this notation carried over into .NET, except only interfaces kept the `I` prefix, but classes and other types dropped their `C`s. This does make non-interface-heavy code easier to look at, but can cause ambiguity if you begin a class name with a 2-letter acronym beginning with `I` (as two-letter acronyms must be completely capitalised according to the the .NET style guidelines), but this is rare.

(I note that generic type name placeholders are prefixed with `T` too, e.g. `TKey` and `TValue` in `Dictionary`).

An example of why this is necessary is when dealing with collections in .NET, if you're building a reusable library and don't want to expose implementation details (e.g. if you use `List<T>` or `T[]` as an underlying collection field type), you can use `IList<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` which are interfaces. If the interface was simply called `List<T>` it would conflict with the actual type `List<T>`, and `ReadOnlyList<T>` (an interface) might get confused with `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (a class).

You might argue that this wouldn't be a problem if classes and interfaces had a different namespace. C does this: `struct` types and scalars exist in different namespaces, which unfortunately means that every time a `struct` type name is used, its usage must be prefixed with `struct` (e.g. a declaration: `struct Foo foo`). People workaround this by using `typedef` with anonymous structs, but I feel the end-result is messy (and the Linux kernel coding guidelines prohibit this too).

In Java, however, interfaces are not prefixed with `I` but instead have class-like names. Whether this is "correct" or "better" is entirely up for debate. C++ does not have interface types, just pure-abstract classes and multiple-inheritance, so the `I` prefix isn't typically seen at all outside of COM.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote again just for that first sentence.  This last holdout of Hungarian notation forced upon the community as a vendor convention irritates me to no end :)

Comment: Try creating interfaces related to IATA or ICAO :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah but why would you want an interface for those haha. They're just properties on the Airport.

Comment: Sounds good to me!  Pretty annoying to see that prefix all over and just wanted to understand it a little better.  And, yes, great first sentence!  Much appreciated!